# Xtext org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException: Unable to open editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, xtext

I want to open an XText editor in my tool.
I have used the example xtext grammar org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel.

```
org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException: Unable to open editor, unknown editor ID: 'org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel.Domainmodel'
```

1. I have a new extension point to add a view in Eclipse
   [image]
2. I try to open the XText editor like below:

   ```
    public class LabelView extends ViewPart {
    private Label label;

    public LabelView() {
        super();
    }

    public void setFocus() {
        label.setFocus();
    }

    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        label = new Label(parent, 0);
        label.setText("Hello World");

        IFile workspaceFile = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(new Path("C:\\xtext\\ex.dmodel"));

        IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

        try {
            IEditorPart openEditor = IDE.openEditor(page, workspaceFile,
                    "org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel.Domainmodel", true);
        } catch (PartInitException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
   ```

   }
3. The id of the editor ("**org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel.Domainmodel**") is defined as id in plugin.xml of org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel.ui (which extends epoint="org.eclipse.ui.editors")

[image]

4. It seems that the editor is not loaded, as the code below doesn't find a loaded editor with my id:

   > ```
   > IConfigurationElement[] configs = Platform.getExtensionRegistry()
   >                   .getConfigurationElementsFor("org.eclipse.ui.editors");
   >           for (IConfigurationElement currentConfElement : configs) {
   >               if (currentConfElement.getAttribute("id").equals(eId)) {
   >                   try {
   >                       XtextEditor editor = (XtextEditor) currentConfElement.createExecutableExtension("class");
   >                   } catch (CoreException ee) {
   >                       ee.printStackTrace();
   >                   }
   >                   break;
   >               }
   >           }
   > ```

Comment: So how are you running this? Are you testing using 'Run as Eclipse Application'? Does the run configuration contain all your plug-ins?

Comment: I have used a target platform. I just tried to run it before setting the TP and this works, but after runing the config using TP it doesn't load the xtext editor first of all.

Comment: The Target Platform doesn't determine what plug-ins are included when you run the application. If you are using Run As Eclipse Application you must look at the Run Configuration to see which plug-ins are being included in the run.

Comment: any reason you dont use the embedded editor if you want to have an embedded editor?

Comment: Yes, this is what I try to add now.